# asp.net core identity services unable unable to resolve : SignInManager , UserManager , RoleManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity

Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager

Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager

Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager

i have added app.UseAuthorization();

and tried these :

```
            var builder = services.addidentitycore<pdn1user>();
            var identitybuilder = new identitybuilder(builder.usertype, builder.services);
            identitybuilder.addentityframeworkstores<accountdbcontext>();
            identitybuilder.addsigninmanager<signinmanager<pdn1user>>();
```

- 

```
            services.adddefaultidentity<pdn1user>(options => options.signin.requireconfirmedaccount = false)
                .addentityframeworkstores<accountdbcontext>();
```

- 

```
        services.adddefaultidentity<pdn1user>(options => options.signin.requireconfirmedaccount = true)
      .addroles<identityrole>()
        .addentityframeworkstores<accountdbcontext>();
```

Answer (score 0):

after 3 days i figured it out with help of a friend :

### i removed below from IdentityHostingStartup.cs

### Replace your identityName

```
 services.AddDefaultIdentity<'identityName'User>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<'identityName'Context>();
```

### and wrote below in services.cs

```
services.AddIdentity<'identityName'User, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
            })
   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<'identityName'Context>()
   .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```